# Improve flow chart template with rectangle split

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-styles, shapes

I'm try to build a flow chart template:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=2.00cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=2.00cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,shapes,arrows,shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{
   papDescision/.style = {
         diamond,
         draw, 
         text width = 20 mm, 
         align = center, 
         text badly centered,
         inner sep = 1 pt,
         font=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
         line width = 1,
         minimum width = 30mm,
         minimum height = 7mm,
      },
   papStart/.style = {
         rectangle,
         draw, 
         align = center, 
         text width = 20 mm, 
         text badly centered,
         inner sep = 4 pt,
         rounded corners,
         font=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
         line width = 1,
         minimum width = 30mm,
         minimum height = 7mm,
      },
   papEnd/.style = {
         rectangle,
         draw, 
         align = center, 
         text width = 20 mm, 
         text badly centered,
         inner sep = 4 pt,
         rounded corners,
         font=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
         line width = 1,
         minimum width = 30mm,
         minimum height = 7mm,
      },
   papData/.style = {
         trapezium,
         draw, 
         align = center, 
         text width = 20 mm, 
         text badly centered,
         inner sep = 4 pt,
         trapezium left angle=70,
         trapezium right angle=110,
         font=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
         line width = 1,
         minimum width = 30mm,
         minimum height = 7mm,
      },
   papFunction/.style = {
         draw,
         rectangle split,
         rectangle split horizontal,
         rectangle split parts = 3,
         align = center, 
%        text width = 4.5 em, 
         text badly centered,
         inner sep = 4 pt,
         font=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
         line width = 1,
         minimum width = 30mm,
         minimum height = 7mm,
      },
   papInstruction/.style = {
         rectangle,
         draw,
         align = center, 
         text width = 20 mm, 
         text badly centered,
         inner sep = 4 pt,
         font=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
         line width = 1,
         minimum width = 30mm,
         minimum height = 7mm,
      },
   papLine/.style = {
         draw,
         -stealth,
         font=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
         line width = 1,
      },
}

\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\papYes}{\ding{51}}
\newcommand{\papNo}{\ding{55}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 12mm, auto]
\node [papStart] (Start1)
   {Start};
\node [papDescision, below of = Start1, yshift= -9mm] (Desc1)
   {word word word};
\node [papData, below of = Desc1, yshift= -10mm] (Trap1)  
   {word};
\node [papFunction,  below of = Trap1] (Func1)
   {\nodepart{two}\shortstack{Predefined\\Process}};
\node [papFunction,  right of = Trap1, xshift=25mm] (Func2) 
   {\nodepart{two}word};
\node [papInstruction,  below of = Func2] (Func3)  
   {word};
\node [papEnd, below of = Func1, yshift= -3mm] (End)
   {word};

\coordinate [below of = Func1, yshift= 5mm] (join1);


\path [papLine] (Start1) -- (Desc1);
\path [papLine] (Desc1) -- node [at start] {\papYes} (Trap1);
\path [papLine] (Func3) |- (join1);
\path [papLine] (Func1) -- (End);
\path [papLine] (Desc1) -| node [at start] {\papNo} (Func2);
\path [papLine] (Func2) -- (Func3);
\path [papLine] (Trap1) -- (Func1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}!
```

[image: result of the code above]

How can I setup `papFunction` for a minimum width an smaller stripes at the sides?

Thanks and regards
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set `rectangle split empty part width` to a negative length. For example, adding `rectangle split empty part width=-8pt` produces:

[image: narrowed splits]